# How to use the hypercall of kvm?

Tags: virtualization, kvm

I want to use the hypercall of kvm to communicate (just send strings, it is uni-directional) between the guest and vmm instead of creating a network channel between the guest os and host. 
I have only found the file arch/x86/include/asm/kvm_para.h in linux kernel? Is it similar to the system call of linux? How can I call these functions from the user level process running inside the guest os? Is there any manual or documents for this? Or can you give some examples of utilizing this mechanisms. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My opinion is that you can add a specific driver in guest OS, which can communicate with host easily via share memory or other methods. With the driver, you can do very complicated tasks with high performance.

Answer (score 1):

More than a bit late, but if you want to send strings, you can create a serial device in kvm/qemu and use standard serial output from your application.  qemu has a very flexible virtual serial port system.